# E/StorageUtil( 6584): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: b.a.d.p.d.a: Please sign in before trying to get a token

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am receiving the following error related to my Firebase code to save both an image, date and number of waste items. Or is it possible this is an error related to my Firebase configuration?

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:wasteagram/model/waste.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final bool isUpdating;  


  CameraScreen({this.isUpdating = true}); 

  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(); 
  Waste _currentWaste = Waste(); 

  Widget _buildDateField() {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey, 
      child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Date'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), 
        validator: (String value) {
          if(value.isEmpty){
            return 'Date required'; 
          }
          if(value.length < 3 || value.length > 20) {
            return 'Name must be more than 3 or less than 20'; 
          }
          return null;
        },

        onSaved: (String value) {
          _currentWaste.wastedate = value; 
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildWasteNumber() {
    return Form(

          child: TextFormField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Number'),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20), 
        validator: (value) {
          if(value.isEmpty){
            return 'Number required'; 
          }
          return null;
        },

        onSaved: (String value) {
          String wasteNum = _currentWaste.wastenumber.toString();
          wasteNum = value; 
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _saveWaste(context) {

    print("saveWaste Called"); 
    if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return "FALSE"; 
    }

    _formKey.currentState.save(); 

    print("form saved");

    uploadItems(_currentWaste, widget.isUpdating, image);  


    print("date ${_currentWaste.wastedate}"); 
    print("number ${_currentWaste.wastenumber.toString()}");
    print("_imageFile ${image.toString()}");
  }

  File image; 

  void getImage() async {
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); 
    setState( () {}); 
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (image == null) {
      return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Wasteagram')
      ), 
      body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Select Photo'),
            onPressed: () {
              getImage(); 
            },
          ),
        ),
      ); 
    } else {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Wasteagram')
          ), 
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
            Image.file(image),
            SizedBox(height: 40), 
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Select Photo'),
              onPressed: () {
                getImage(); 
              }
            ), 
            _buildDateField(),
            _buildWasteNumber(),
              ],
            ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => _saveWaste(context),
            child: Icon(Icons.save),
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          ),

        ); 
    }
  }
}

uploadItems(Waste waste, bool isUpdating, File localFile) async {
  if (localFile != null) {
    print("uploading image"); 

    var fileExtension = path.extension(localFile.path); 
    print(fileExtension); 

    var uuid = Uuid().v4(); 

    final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = 
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('/$uuid$fileExtension'); 

      await firebaseStorageRef.putFile(localFile).onComplete.catchError(
        (onError){
          print(onError); 
          return false; 
        }
      ); 

      String url = await firebaseStorageRef.getDownloadURL(); 
      print("download url: $url"); 
      _uploadWaste(waste, isUpdating, imageUrl: url); 
  } else {
    print("skipping image upload"); 
    _uploadWaste(waste, isUpdating); 

  }
}

_uploadWaste(Waste waste, bool isUpdating, {String imageUrl}) async {
  CollectionReference wasteRef = Firestore.instance.collection('todolist'); 

  if(imageUrl != null) {
    waste.image = imageUrl; 
  }

  if(isUpdating) {

    waste.updatedAt = Timestamp.now(); 

    await wasteRef.document(waste.id).updateData(waste.toMap()); 
  print("updated waste with id: ${waste.id}"); 
  } else {

    DocumentReference documentRef = await wasteRef.add(waste.toMap()); 

    waste.id = documentRef.documentID; 

    print("uploaded waste successfully: ${waste.toString()}"); 

    await documentRef.setData(waste.toMap(), merge: true); 
  }


}
```

The error is as follows -

E/StorageUtil( 6584): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: b.a.d.p.d.a: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest( 6584): no auth token for request

Answer (score 1):

Check all these

1) After updating to the latest dependency versions, make sure that push notifications still work as expected.

2) Review the Firebase installations documentation. Also, make sure to monitor FCM registration token generation using the #onNewToken implementation.

3)Apps that use the Firebase auto-initialization process and the Gradle plugin to convert google-services.json into resources are unaffected. However, apps that create their own FirebaseOptions instances must provide a valid API key, Firebase project ID, and application ID.